# Why is my CloudWatch rule triggered but not invoking my Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I have created a Lambda function using the CDK.

In my Java application, I am programmatically creating a CloudWatch Event Rule with a target pointing to the function via its ARN.

The CloudWatch rule gets triggered but it fails to invoke the Lambda. When I manually add the CloudWatch rule as a trigger for the Lambda from AWS Console, the function does get invoked.

CDK code

```js
private createPregameEventsLambda(props: InfraStackProps) {
        const lambdaEnvVars = {
            'Domain': props.stage,
            'Region': props.region,
            'ResourceNamePrefix': props.resourceNamePrefix
        };

        const pregameEventsLambda = new Lambda(this, "PregameEvents-Lambda", {
            ...props,
            name: LambdaConfig.PREGAME_EVENTS_LAMBDA.name,
            handler: LambdaConfig.PREGAME_EVENTS_LAMBDA.handler,
            environment: {
                variables: lambdaEnvVars
            },
            role: this.lambdaExecutionRole
        }).getFunction()
}
```

Java application:

```java
public void createCloudWatchRule(final LiveEventIdRelationInfo info) {
        final String smpId = info.getSmpId();
        final Date date = new Date(startTime);
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);

        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));
        final String cronExpression =  getCronExpression(calendar);

        final PutRuleRequest putRuleRequest = new PutRuleRequest()
                .withScheduleExpression(cronExpression)
                .withName(ruleName);
        cloudWatchEventClient.putRule(putRuleRequest);

        final Target target = new Target()
                .withId(LAMBDA_TARGET_ID)
                .withArn(functionArn)
                .withInput(jsonString);
        final PutTargetsRequest putTargetsRequest = new PutTargetsRequest()
                .withRule(ruleName)
                .withTargets(target);
        cloudWatchEventClient.putTargets(putTargetsRequest);
    }
```

Console shows that the Rule created has the correct Lambda ARN but it still does not get invoked.

Is there an `InvokeFunction` permission I need to add to the CDK code?

Am I missing permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an `InvokeFunction` permission I need to add to the CDK code?

No, this isn't related to your CDK code, since you're creating a new EventBridge (CloudWatch) rule outside of your CDK code. You're not creating the rule using the CDK so it's not the right place to look.

**Your Lambda function is missing a resource-based IAM policy, which grants EventBridge & specifically your created rule, to invoke it.**

Since you're creating the rule & target *programmatically*, you will also need to grant this permission *programmatically* using [`AddPermission`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/lambda/LambdaClient.html#addPermission-software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.AddPermissionRequest-) & the [`LambdaClient`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/lambda/LambdaClient.html) in your Java application.

Among other things, `AddPermission` allows you to set a source ARN which is the ARN of the AWS resource that invokes the function. This would be the ARN of the EventBridge rule.

This is not *required* however if you do not specify the source, do note that other accounts could potentially configure resources in their account to invoke your Lambda function. As such, **I'd recommend always setting the source ARN**.

Applying the above to your code, `cloudWatchEventClient.putRule(putRuleRequest);` will actually [return](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/eventbridge/EventBridgeClient.html#putRule-software.amazon.awssdk.services.eventbridge.model.PutRuleRequest-) the ARN of the created rule in the [`PutRuleReponse`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/eventbridge/model/PutRuleResponse.html) via the `ruleArn()` method i.e.

```java
final PutRuleResponse response = cloudWatchEventClient.putRule(putRuleRequest);
final String ruleArn = response.ruleArn();
```

Once you have this value captured, create & send a [`AddPermissionRequest`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/lambda/model/AddPermissionRequest.html) to grant the necessary permission.

This should work using the AWS SDK for Java 2.x:

```java
public void createCloudWatchRule(final LiveEventIdRelationInfo info) {
    ...
    final PutRuleRequest putRuleRequest = new PutRuleRequest()
            .withScheduleExpression(cronExpression)
            .withName(ruleName);

    final PutRuleResponse response = cloudWatchEventClient.putRule(putRuleRequest);
    final String ruleArn = response.ruleArn();

    final Target target = new Target()
            .withId(LAMBDA_TARGET_ID)
            .withArn(functionArn)
            .withInput(jsonString);
    final PutTargetsRequest putTargetsRequest = new PutTargetsRequest()
            .withRule(ruleName)
            .withTargets(target);
    cloudWatchEventClient.putTargets(putTargetsRequest);

    final AddPermissionRequest addPermissionRequest = new AddPermissionRequest()
        .withFunctionName(functionArn)
        .withStatementId("sid-" + LAMBDA_TARGET_ID)
        .withAction("lambda:InvokeFunction")
        .withPrincipal("events.amazonaws.com")
        .withSourceArn(ruleArn)
        .build();
    
    lambdaClient.addPermission(addPermissionRequest);
}
```

If you're using AWS SDK for Java 1.x, the same concepts apply - there will be minor syntax differences but cross reference the above links with the v1 docs and you'll be able to easily figure it out.